# Delay when calling setState multiple times

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am developing an application that has two listings. When you click on a product from the first listing the second listing is incremented.

My problem is that there is a delay in clicking the products in the first listing. It takes milliseconds. And I discovered that the delay occurs when setState is called. SetState causes a slight delay.

if I comment the setState everything works without delay.

**my code**

```
selectProduct(item, quantidade){

  .... 

  this.setState({ itensNota });
}
```

**my problem**

[image]

I do not know the reason for the problem. I believe the problem happens due to the react native rendering the entire screen every time the setState is called. But I do not know how to solve this problem. The customer complained about the delay and I need to solve this problem. can anybody help me?

**************** **EDIT** ****************

my complete code

https://github.com/renatosistemasvc/temo/blob/master/subir.js

Comment: setState is async... Would need to see more code to help... This will probably help you... https://medium.freecodecamp.org/get-pro-with-react-setstate-in-10-minutes-d38251d1c781

Comment: Start with `console.log()` in your components and start following first how many times they re-render and then due to which prop.

Comment: Could you add more code? So we can see how you're updating the lists, and understand what is the cause of the latency. `setState` is not the problem, but it's the piece of code that makes the problem visible.

Comment: @romin21 https://github.com/renatosistemasvc/temo/blob/master/subir.js

Answer (score 0):

I read your code and seens to be ok.

You can try to use setState with function, to run synchronized with state tasks:

```
    selectProduct(item, quantidade) {

        this.setState(state => {

            let valorTotalNota = 0;
            let itensNota = [];
            let ind = false;

            for (let i in state.itensNota) {

                let a = state.itensNota[i];

                if (item.id == a.produto_id) {

                    ind = true;

                    //SE EXISTE ESTOQUE DISPONÍVEL INCREMENTA, SE NÃO, MANTÉM QUANTIDADE ANTERIOR
                    let refQtd = (item.estoque >= (a.quantidade + quantidade)) ? a.quantidade + quantidade : a.quantidade;

                    valorTotalNota = Decimal.add(valorTotalNota, Decimal.mul(refQtd, a.preco)).toString();
                    itensNota.push({ cod: null, nome: a.nome, preco: a.preco, desconto: a.desconto, imgTablet: a.imgTablet, quantidade: refQtd, estoque: a.estoque, produto_id: a.produto_id });



                } else {

                    valorTotalNota = Decimal.add(valorTotalNota, Decimal.mul(a.quantidade, a.preco)).toString();
                    itensNota.push({ cod: null, nome: a.nome, preco: a.preco, desconto: a.desconto, imgTablet: a.imgTablet, quantidade: a.quantidade, estoque: a.estoque, produto_id: a.produto_id })

                }

            }

            if (!ind && item.estoque > 0) {

                valorTotalNota = Decimal.add(valorTotalNota, Decimal.mul(quantidade, item.preco)).toString();
                itensNota.splice(0, 0, { cod: null, nome: item.nome, preco: item.preco, desconto: item.desconto, imgTablet: item.imgTablet, quantidade: quantidade, estoque: item.estoque, produto_id: item.id });

            }

            return {
                ...state,
                itensNota,
                valor_distribuido: valorTotalNota
            }
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The code seems OK. One thing that might make the performance better is to make `selectProduct` async. This way, it returns right away and the list items won't be so slow when being pressed, although the update of the other list will still take some time:

```
selectProduct = async (item, quantidade) => { ... }
```

Other things that you should take into consideration are:

- Disable  the remote debugger. Sometimes React Native apps are a bit slow when debugging remotely.
- Test the app in another device (preferably a better one). If it behaves fine in that device, then it's the device you're using currently that is causing the problem, because of its low parameters.